# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{\ln(2)^n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

would the sum from 1 to infinity of $\frac{n^3}{(\ln{2})^n}$ converge? In the limit n tends to infinity the denominator grows more quickly and so the terms go to zero.

Using the ratio test I get $\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3\ln{2}}$ but im not sure if $(n+1)$ grows fast enough to make the ratio greater than one.

Comment: Have you tried calculating $\ln(2)$?  (Without a calculator, the fact that $2<e$ will give you enough information.)

Comment: $2 <e$, so... is the necessary condition fulfilled?

Comment: I just assumed it would be bigger than 1... Wow im bad. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3\ln^n2 ~=~ \frac{\ln^32+4\ln^22+\ln2}{(1-\ln2)^4}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $\ln 2\simeq 0.69$, and in particular $\ln 2 \in (0,1)$. Therefore, $\frac{n^3}{(\ln 2)^n} > n^3$ (actually *much* bigger), and you can conclude easily that the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

No, because ln(2) is less than one, so the terms clearly are all positive and tend to infinity, so the sequence diverges.

But for any value of x bigger than e, this is true, as we then have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{a^x}$ (where $a = ln(x)>1$), and we can use the ratio test to get $\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^3/a$. This limit tends to 1/a by L'hopital's rule, so we know by the ratio test that this sequence converges.